On a major scale why are there half steps between B and C and between E and F?
On a major scale why are there half steps between b and c and between e and f?
It seems like from a to b to c to d to e to f to g to a should all differ in the same "amount" of tone from eachother.
Is there something about the fundamental physics of wave's and sound that makes this so? Or is it just a convention that humans decided?
I'm sorry, I wish I could ask this question better. I appreciate any responses!

I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about music theory, not physics. Music Practice & Theory Stackexchange may be able to answer it.

I was wondering if there is an underlying physical reason for this. Like is there number of peak amplitudes in there harmonic resonances doubled or something? Idk

You actually start from a wrong premise. The 7 notes are not equally spaced. It's the 12 semitones that are equally spaced. The reason that B-C and E-F don't have intermediate semitones has to do with how earlier notations were mapped onto the 12-semitone scale...but someone on the other Stackexchange will be able to explain it better than me.

The Wikipedia article Equal Temperament might also give you some useful information (but I don't think it addresses your question directly).

This is a deeper question than you might think, and goes back to the foundations of western music, and the convention of equal temperament.  You will get a much more thorough and helpful answer on Music Practice and Theory.

@RC_23, As I understand it the 12-tone scale is not strictly tied equal temperament. For example, just intonation can also be used with a 12-tone scale. And that equal temperament was known previously but didn't come into wide use until the 19th C. Equal temperament is really only needed if you want to play in different keys on the same instrument --- very useful for pianos, but not so important for trumpets (for example).

There is some interesting physics & mathematics underlying the answer to this question, but you really need to understand some important music theory first before you can properly appreciate why the physics is relevant.

The physics
Just intonation prescribes the simple rational ratios of frequencies that intervals are built on. In particular, an octave is a ratio of $2:1$, and a "perfect fifth" is a ratio of $3:2$. This is because superpositions of waves in these simple integer ratios have nice periodic waveforms. For instance, the periodicity of $A\sin(3t)+B\sin(2t)$ is $2\pi$.
The mathematics
The pitch of notes is perceptually uniform on a log scale (that is, raising the pitch by some degree is equivalent to multiplying its frequency by some constant). To fit $N$ notes in an octave in equal temperament, the multiplicative factor between adjacent notes would be $2^{1/N}$. This means that the ratio of frequencies of intervals will be irrational, so they can never equal the ratios prescribed by just intonation. But, it happens that, for certain values of $N$, these irrational ratios are very good approximations for just intonation. Western music has been built on the 12-TET scale, that is, setting $N=12$. As an example, $2^{7/12}=1.4983\approx1.5=3/2$, so this is a good approximation for the interval now known as a "perfect fifth." Of course, there are other choices of $N$ that also well-approximate the just intonation intervals, such as 22-TET. The question of what not-too-large choices of $N$ can well-approximate the just intonation intervals can be posed as a mathematical one. Many of these other tuning systems are pervasive in music outside the Western culture.
The music theory
The major scale is a particularly consonant diatonic scale. In particular, out of the diatonic scales, it's chosen because the 7th scale degree (the "leading tone") has a strong tendency towards the octave (the "tonic"). More generally, a diatonic scale is a particular instance of a heptatonic scale, which you can read about at the provided links, or on the Music Practice & Theory StackExchange!

RE: "Once you've chosen to use 12-TET, it's time to choose a scale!"  As I understand it, the scales came first and equal temperament was developed to allow playing multiple scales on a single instrument. Getting details like this right is why this question ought to be on the Music Theory stack.

Yeah, this answer gets the history backward. We have the twelve-tone scale because raising a tone through the "circle of fifths," increasing its frequency by a factor $(3/2)^{12}≈129.7$, is quite close to raising the same tone by seven octaves, a factor of $2^{7}=128$.

Edited to remove the misleading sentence.
